# the the popup window ("flyout") of a like button doesn't show up in a chrome extension

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, facebook-like

i am trying to put a like button on a page in a chrome extension that i've developed.

i use the simple XFBML version:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.mydomain.com/page?param=1&amp;otherparam=2" send="false" layout="standard" width="400" show_faces="false" font="arial" ref="chrome_notification"></fb:like>
```

and of course i use the JavaScript SDK.

when i upload this page into my webserver, everything works just fine.
but when i run this page within my chrome extension, the like button itself works just fine, but the comment popup doesn't show.

in addition - i get these error masseges in the console:

> **Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL** chrome-extension://eindnjdghfmigkecgibjclhdnadlnbhm/../mypage.html from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df3d383d278%26origin%3Dchrome-extension%253A%252F%252Feindnjdghfmigkecgibjclhdnadlnbhm%252Ff44dd2768%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&font=arial&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2F%3Fparam%3D1%26otherparam%3D2&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&ref=chrome_notification&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=false&width=400. **Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

and -

> **Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL** https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=158698534219579&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df3d383d278%26origin%3Dchrome-extension%253A%252F%252Feindnjdghfmigkecgibjclhdnadlnbhm%252Ff44dd2768%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&extended_social_context=false&font=arial&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2F%3Fparam%3D1%26otherparam%3D2&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&ref=chrome_notification&sdk=joey&send=false&show_faces=false&width=400 from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/**comment_widget_shell.php**?api_key=&locale=en_US&master_frame_name=f38cd100f8&sdk=joey. **Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

can anyone help me to find a solution for this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could it possibly by related to this known Facebook bug?

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293075054049400

Basically, one gets this behavior if secure browsing is enabled on the Facebook user's account.