# Facebook Like not working on Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, facebook-like

I am running the latest version of Chrome on Mac Lion.  I added a FB like button to my page which works fine on Firefox but does not work on Chrome for some reason. There seems to be a quick window pop-up which tries to load and then it disappears without the "Like" taking place.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/luisp128/X7SDR/3/

I thought it might be related to this prior question, but FB said this issue was already resolved: [the the popup window ("flyout") of a like button doesn't show up in a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852392/the-the-popup-window-flyout-of-a-like-button-doesnt-show-up-in-a-chrome-ext)

Comment: @Mr.Alien, really?  I guess it must be my security settings... Ok, removing the question

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that you must be logged into Facebook within each browser for the FB buttons to appear in that browser (otherwise the buttons have no context).  If not, the buttons are not shown.

So, if you're seeing this problem, open a new tab, log into FB, and then refresh the original tab - the buttons will then appear (assuming there isn't a second problem)>